# Android - NullPointerException with storage == null

Tags: android, nullpointerexception

Hi I'm having problems with an android app I'm building. It is a mediaplayer that allows playing at the background. It keeps crashing when I try to run it with the mentioned exception. I would really appreciate some help on how to stop this error please. Here's my Main Activity:

```
package com.example.katelee.mp3player;

import android.os.Environment;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

import com.example.katelee.mp3player.myService.LocalBinder;

import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.content.ComponentName;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.ServiceConnection;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SeekBar;
import android.widget.SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.io.File;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity  {

    private Intent i;
    myService mService;
    boolean mBound = false;

    private Button btnPlayPause, btnStop;
    private SeekBar seekBar;
    MP3Player mediaPlayer;
    private TextView tx;

    public String selectedMusic;
    File musicDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath()+ "/Music/");

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        btnPlayPause = (Button) findViewById(R.id.play);
        btnStop = (Button) findViewById(R.id.stop);

        final ListView lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_view);
        seekBar = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.seek_bar);
        tx = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);

        mediaPlayer = MP3Player.getInstance();

        btnPlayPause.setOnClickListener(new OnClickPlayPauseListener());
        btnStop.setOnClickListener(new OnClickStopListener());
        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> myAdapter, View myView, int myItemInt,long mylng) {
                File selectedFromList =(File) (lv.getItemAtPosition(myItemInt));
                Log.d("g53mdp", selectedFromList.getAbsolutePath());
                selectedMusic = selectedFromList.getAbsolutePath();
            }
        });

        File list[] = musicDir.listFiles();
        lv.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<File>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, list));

    }
    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        // Bind to LocalService
        i = new Intent(this, myService.class);
        bindService(i, mConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        // Unbind from the service
        if (mBound) {
            unbindService(mConnection);
            mBound = false;
        }
    }

    private class OnClickPlayPauseListener implements OnClickListener {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            if(mBound)
            {
                if(mService.getState() == MP3Player.MP_STATE.PLAYING) {
                    mService.pause();
                }
                else if (mService.getState() == MP3Player.MP_STATE.PAUSED) {
                    mService.start();
                }
                else {
                    seekBar = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.seek_bar);

                    configureSeekBar(seekBar);
                    Uri uri = Uri.parse(selectedMusic);
                    mService.playLocalFile(getApplicationContext(), uri);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private class OnClickStopListener implements OnClickListener {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            mService.stop();
        }
    }


    /** Defines callback for service binding, passed to bindService() */
    private ServiceConnection mConnection = new ServiceConnection() {

        @Override
        public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName className, IBinder service) {

            LocalBinder binder = (LocalBinder) service;
            mService = binder.getService();
            mBound = true;
        }

        @Override
        public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName arg0) {
            mBound = false;
        }
    };

    public void configureSeekBar(SeekBar seekBar) {
        this.seekBar = seekBar;

        new Thread(new SeekBarThread()).start();
    }

    private class SeekBarThread implements Runnable {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                while (mService.getState().equals(MP3Player.MP_STATE.STOPPED)) {
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                }
                seekBar.setMax(mService.getDuration());
                seekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new MyOnSeekBarChangedListener());
                while (true) {
                    if (mService.getState() != MP3Player.MP_STATE.STOPPED) {
                        if(mService.getCurrentPosition() < mService.getDuration()){
                            seekBar.setProgress(mService.getCurrentPosition());
                        }
                    }
                    else {
                        seekBar.setProgress(0);
                    }
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(1000);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
            catch(Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    private class MyOnSeekBarChangedListener implements OnSeekBarChangeListener {

        @Override
        public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromTouch) {
            if(fromTouch) {
                mService.seekTo(progress);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
            //Empty method
        }

        @Override
        public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
            //Empty method
        }
    }

}
```

And this is my service class:

```
package com.example.katelee.mp3player;

import com.example.katelee.mp3player.MP3Player.MP_STATE;
import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.media.MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Binder;
import android.os.IBinder;

public class myService extends Service implements OnCompletionListener {

    private MP3Player mediaPlayer = MP3Player.getInstance();

    private final IBinder mBinder = new LocalBinder();


    public class LocalBinder extends Binder {
        myService getService() {
            return myService.this;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return mBinder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    public synchronized MP_STATE getState() {
        return mediaPlayer.getState();
    }

    public void start() {
        mediaPlayer.start();
    }

    public void pause() {
        mediaPlayer.pause();
    }

    public void stop() {
        mediaPlayer.stop();
    }

    public void playLocalFile(Context c, Uri filepath) {
        mediaPlayer.playLocalFile(c, filepath);
    }

    public int getDuration() {
        return mediaPlayer.getDuration();
    }

    public int getCurrentPosition() {
        return mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition();
    }
    public void seekTo(int sec)
    {
        mediaPlayer.seekTo(sec);
    }
}
```

My MP3Player class:

```
package com.example.katelee.mp3player;

import java.io.IOException;

import android.content.Context;
import android.media.AudioManager;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.net.Uri;

public class MP3Player extends MediaPlayer {

    private static MP3Player myMediaPlayer;
    private MP_STATE state;

    public enum MP_STATE {
        ERROR,
        PLAYING,
        PAUSED,
        STOPPED
    }

    public static MP3Player getInstance() {
        if (myMediaPlayer == null) {
            myMediaPlayer = new MP3Player();
        }
        return myMediaPlayer;
    }

    private MP3Player() {
        state = MP3Player.MP_STATE.STOPPED;
    }

    @Override
    public void start() {
        state = MP_STATE.PLAYING;
    }

    @Override
    public void pause() {
        state = MP_STATE.PAUSED;
    }

    @Override
    public void stop() {
        state = MP_STATE.STOPPED;
        super.stop();
        super.reset();
    }


    public void playLocalFile(Context c, Uri filepath) {
        if (!state.equals(MP_STATE.STOPPED)) {
            stop();
        }
        setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
        setOnPreparedListener(new MyOnPreparedListener());
        try {
            setDataSource(c, filepath);
            prepareAsync();
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (SecurityException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }


    public synchronized MP_STATE getState() {
        return state;
    }


    private class MyOnPreparedListener implements OnPreparedListener {
        @Override
        public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
            mediaPlayer.start();
        }
    }
    public int getCurrentPosition() {

        return super.getCurrentPosition();

    }
    public int getDuration()
    {
        return super.getDuration();
    }
    public void seekTo(int sec){
        super.seekTo(sec);
    }

}
```

Here's the logcat:

```
12-08 01:03:48.488 13915-13915/? I/art: Not late-enabling -Xcheck:jni (already on)
12-08 01:03:48.519 13915-13921/? E/art: Failed sending reply to debugger: Broken pipe
12-08 01:03:48.520 13915-13921/? I/art: Debugger is no longer active
12-08 01:03:48.554 13915-13915/? W/art: Failed execv(/system/bin/dex2oat --runtime-arg -classpath --runtime-arg  --debuggable --instruction-set=x86 --instruction-set-features=smp,ssse3,-sse4.1,-sse4.2,-avx,-avx2 --runtime-arg -Xrelocate --boot-image=/system/framework/boot.art --runtime-arg -Xms64m --runtime-arg -Xmx512m --instruction-set-variant=x86 --instruction-set-features=default --dex-file=/data/app/com.example.katelee.mp3player-1/split_lib_dependencies_apk.apk --oat-file=/data/dalvik-cache/x86/data@app@com.example.katelee.mp3player-1@split_lib_dependencies_apk.apk@classes.dex) because non-0 exit status
12-08 01:03:48.671 13915-13915/? W/art: Failed execv(/system/bin/dex2oat --runtime-arg -classpath --runtime-arg  --debuggable --instruction-set=x86 --instruction-set-features=smp,ssse3,-sse4.1,-sse4.2,-avx,-avx2 --runtime-arg -Xrelocate --boot-image=/system/framework/boot.art --runtime-arg -Xms64m --runtime-arg -Xmx512m --instruction-set-variant=x86 --instruction-set-features=default --dex-file=/data/app/com.example.katelee.mp3player-1/split_lib_slice_0_apk.apk --oat-file=/data/dalvik-cache/x86/data@app@com.example.katelee.mp3player-1@split_lib_slice_0_apk.apk@classes.dex) because non-0 exit status
12-08 01:03:48.692 13915-13915/? W/art: Failed execv(/system/bin/dex2oat --runtime-arg -classpath --runtime-arg  --debuggable --instruction-set=x86 --instruction-set-features=smp,ssse3,-sse4.1,-sse4.2,-avx,-avx2 --runtime-arg -Xrelocate --boot-image=/system/framework/boot.art --runtime-arg -Xms64m --runtime-arg -Xmx512m --instruction-set-variant=x86 --instruction-set-features=default --dex-file=/data/app/com.example.katelee.mp3player-1/split_lib_slice_1_apk.apk --oat-file=/data/dalvik-cache/x86/data@app@com.example.katelee.mp3player-1@split_lib_slice_1_apk.apk@classes.dex) because non-0 exit status
12-08 01:03:48.736 13915-13915/? W/art: Failed execv(/system/bin/dex2oat --runtime-arg -classpath --runtime-arg  --debuggable --instruction-set=x86 --instruction-set-features=smp,ssse3,-sse4.1,-sse4.2,-avx,-avx2 --runtime-arg -Xrelocate --boot-image=/system/framework/boot.art --runtime-arg -Xms64m --runtime-arg -Xmx512m --instruction-set-variant=x86 --instruction-set-features=default --dex-file=/data/app/com.example.katelee.mp3player-1/split_lib_slice_2_apk.apk --oat-file=/data/dalvik-cache/x86/data@app@com.example.katelee.mp3player-1@split_lib_slice_2_apk.apk@classes.dex) because non-0 exit status
12-08 01:03:48.758 13915-13915/? W/art: Failed execv(/system/bin/dex2oat --runtime-arg -classpath --runtime-arg  --debuggable --instruction-set=x86 --instruction-set-features=smp,ssse3,-sse4.1,-sse4.2,-avx,-avx2 --runtime-arg -Xrelocate --boot-image=/system/framework/boot.art --runtime-arg -Xms64m --runtime-arg -Xmx512m --instruction-set-variant=x86 --instruction-set-features=default --dex-file=/data/app/com.example.katelee.mp3player-1/split_lib_slice_3_apk.apk --oat-file=/data/dalvik-cache/x86/data@app@com.example.katelee.mp3player-1@split_lib_slice_3_apk.apk@classes.dex) because non-0 exit status
12-08 01:03:48.782 13915-13915/? W/art: Failed execv(/system/bin/dex2oat --runtime-arg -classpath --runtime-arg  --debuggable --instruction-set=x86 --instruction-set-features=smp,ssse3,-sse4.1,-sse4.2,-avx,-avx2 --runtime-arg -Xrelocate --boot-image=/system/framework/boot.art --runtime-arg -Xms64m --runtime-arg -Xmx512m --instruction-set-variant=x86 --instruction-set-features=default --dex-file=/data/app/com.example.katelee.mp3player-1/split_lib_slice_4_apk.apk --oat-file=/data/dalvik-cache/x86/data@app@com.example.katelee.mp3player-1@split_lib_slice_4_apk.apk@classes.dex) because non-0 exit status
12-08 01:03:48.810 13915-13915/? W/art: Failed execv(/system/bin/dex2oat --runtime-arg -classpath --runtime-arg  --debuggable --instruction-set=x86 --instruction-set-features=smp,ssse3,-sse4.1,-sse4.2,-avx,-avx2 --runtime-arg -Xrelocate --boot-image=/system/framework/boot.art --runtime-arg -Xms64m --runtime-arg -Xmx512m --instruction-set-variant=x86 --instruction-set-features=default --dex-file=/data/app/com.example.katelee.mp3player-1/split_lib_slice_5_apk.apk --oat-file=/data/dalvik-cache/x86/data@app@com.example.katelee.mp3player-1@split_lib_slice_5_apk.apk@classes.dex) because non-0 exit status
12-08 01:03:48.832 13915-13915/? W/art: Failed execv(/system/bin/dex2oat --runtime-arg -classpath --runtime-arg  --debuggable --instruction-set=x86 --instruction-set-features=smp,ssse3,-sse4.1,-sse4.2,-avx,-avx2 --runtime-arg -Xrelocate --boot-image=/system/framework/boot.art --runtime-arg -Xms64m --runtime-arg -Xmx512m --instruction-set-variant=x86 --instruction-set-features=default --dex-file=/data/app/com.example.katelee.mp3player-1/split_lib_slice_6_apk.apk --oat-file=/data/dalvik-cache/x86/data@app@com.example.katelee.mp3player-1@split_lib_slice_6_apk.apk@classes.dex) because non-0 exit status
12-08 01:03:48.850 13915-13915/? W/art: Failed execv(/system/bin/dex2oat --runtime-arg -classpath --runtime-arg  --debuggable --instruction-set=x86 --instruction-set-features=smp,ssse3,-sse4.1,-sse4.2,-avx,-avx2 --runtime-arg -Xrelocate --boot-image=/system/framework/boot.art --runtime-arg -Xms64m --runtime-arg -Xmx512m --instruction-set-variant=x86 --instruction-set-features=default --dex-file=/data/app/com.example.katelee.mp3player-1/split_lib_slice_7_apk.apk --oat-file=/data/dalvik-cache/x86/data@app@com.example.katelee.mp3player-1@split_lib_slice_7_apk.apk@classes.dex) because non-0 exit status
12-08 01:03:48.873 13915-13915/? W/art: Failed execv(/system/bin/dex2oat --runtime-arg -classpath --runtime-arg  --debuggable --instruction-set=x86 --instruction-set-features=smp,ssse3,-sse4.1,-sse4.2,-avx,-avx2 --runtime-arg -Xrelocate --boot-image=/system/framework/boot.art --runtime-arg -Xms64m --runtime-arg -Xmx512m --instruction-set-variant=x86 --instruction-set-features=default --dex-file=/data/app/com.example.katelee.mp3player-1/split_lib_slice_8_apk.apk --oat-file=/data/dalvik-cache/x86/data@app@com.example.katelee.mp3player-1@split_lib_slice_8_apk.apk@classes.dex) because non-0 exit status
12-08 01:03:48.911 13915-13915/? W/art: Failed execv(/system/bin/dex2oat --runtime-arg -classpath --runtime-arg  --debuggable --instruction-set=x86 --instruction-set-features=smp,ssse3,-sse4.1,-sse4.2,-avx,-avx2 --runtime-arg -Xrelocate --boot-image=/system/framework/boot.art --runtime-arg -Xms64m --runtime-arg -Xmx512m --instruction-set-variant=x86 --instruction-set-features=default --dex-file=/data/app/com.example.katelee.mp3player-1/split_lib_slice_9_apk.apk --oat-file=/data/dalvik-cache/x86/data@app@com.example.katelee.mp3player-1@split_lib_slice_9_apk.apk@classes.dex) because non-0 exit status
12-08 01:03:48.912 13915-13915/? W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/com.example.katelee.mp3player-1/lib/x86
12-08 01:03:48.914 13915-13915/? I/InstantRun: Starting Instant Run Server for com.example.katelee.mp3player
12-08 01:03:49.413 13915-13915/? W/art: Before Android 4.1, method android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter android.support.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawableCompat.updateTintFilter(android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter, android.content.res.ColorStateList, android.graphics.PorterDuff$Mode) would have incorrectly overridden the package-private method in android.graphics.drawable.Drawable
12-08 01:03:49.911 13915-13915/com.example.katelee.mp3player D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
12-08 01:03:49.913 13915-13915/com.example.katelee.mp3player E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                               Process: com.example.katelee.mp3player, PID: 13915
                                                                               java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.katelee.mp3player/com.example.katelee.mp3player.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: storage == null
                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2416)
                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
                                                                                   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                                   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
                                                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                                                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
                                                                                Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: storage == null
                                                                                   at java.util.Arrays$ArrayList.<init>(Arrays.java:38)
                                                                                   at java.util.Arrays.asList(Arrays.java:155)
                                                                                   at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.<init>(ArrayAdapter.java:137)
                                                                                   at com.example.katelee.mp3player.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:67)
                                                                                   at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6237)
                                                                                   at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107)
                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369)
                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476) 
                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344) 
                                                                                   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                                   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
                                                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
                                                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

I've already included the necessary tag in my Manifest file so the issue should rise from there. I know the problem that my storage is null but I'm pretty sure it is not null so I'm not sure how to tackle this problem :(

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Answer (score 0):

`listFiles()` can return a null, and passing a null array to `ArrayAdapter` causes this problem. Check for null return value and replace with an empty array before passing it to `ArrayAdapter`.